# Change Autolayout at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Is it possible to change autolayout constraints during runtime?

I know you can change the constant, but how would you change different attributes.

For example, NSLayoutAttributeTop to NSLayoutAttributeBottom?

Here is a simple sample of what I hope to achieve, it will set a label top left, then when you press a button it will set the label bottom right.

The initial constraints work as expected, tapping the button doesn't work as expected and throws the infamous "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."

Here is the code I am using:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    self.constraintA = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.topLabel
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:0.0];

    self.constraintB = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.topLabel
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:0.0];

    [self.view addConstraint:self.constraintA];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.constraintB];
}

- (IBAction)tappedChange:(id)sender
{

    [self.view removeConstraints:@[ self.constraintA, self.constraintB ]];

    self.constraintA = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.topLabel
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:0.0];

    self.constraintB = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.topLabel
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                     constant:0.0];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.constraintA];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.constraintB];
    [self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to perform the Remove/Recreate/Add constraint dance on iOS 7 and below. If you are writing for a modern iOS (8 and above) you can create all your constraints at once and then just set the `.active` property on whatever `NSLayoutConstraint` instance you want at any given time.

```
// Move to right
self.leadingConstraint.active = false;
self.trailingConstraint.active = true;

// Move to bottom
self.topConstraint.active = false;
self.bottomConstraint.active = true;
```

[image]

If you are using Interface Builder you can create *all* the constraints that will be needed (note the grayed out constraints that aren't active by default).

[image: Xcode Window Showing Example]

Then when the button is pressed you can deactivate the old constraints and activate the new ones.

If you are ever unsure about the views being shown you can pause the app execution and use the following private API in the debugger to print out a full list of views and constraints:

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

Comment: Isn't that what I am doing? I just tried creating two new constraints versus reusing the existing after they are removed and it still doesn't work. The error is too long to include here, but here is the top line:  "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want..."

Comment: Brian, that's why I was wondering what the other constraints on these views are. That you must have other constraints already on the right-hand side, or the bottom that these new constraints are conflicted with, etc.

Comment: The contents of that error message is actually what you will need to read and understand.

Comment: These are the only two constraints. Nothing was set in code or Interface Builder. I assume since these are UILabels the height and width is intrinsic, so that would provide the required 4 constraints.

Comment: Brian, you can use `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` to see the full list of views and any abiguity.

Comment: Also, IB *will* actually create temporary constraints for you for dimensions you don't set specifically. I often use DCIntrospect-ARC or maybe the new Xcode view debugging to dig into what constraints ended up their at runtime.

Comment: ^1 for `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]`!

Comment: Yes, if you don't have to support iOS 7, you can activate the constraints as Josh mentioned.

Comment: Might want to add in animation code to your answer too.

Comment: Steven, I really appreciate your help on this matter. But it still isn't working as expected with the 'active' approach. The view changes position, but only by a few pixels, not aligned with the bottom/right. I tried po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace] but nothing is listed as ambiguous. I wish it wasn't so hard to do simple layouts with autolayout!

Comment: Steven, I was able to get this working by adding all of the constraints in the storyboard. I still can't solve this using the code, but now I have a solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I like using [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) to manage constraints in code - it's way less writing, easier to read what you wrote six months ago, and the learning curve isn't as head-splitting either.

For example:

```
// Define some constraints, making the top one a @property:
[view1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    self.topConstraint = make.top.equalTo(superview.mas_top).with.offset(padding.top);
    make.left.equalTo(superview.mas_left).with.offset(padding.left);
}];

// Update the top constraint to match the bottom of the superview instead of the top
[view1 mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    self.topConstraint = make.top.equalTo(superview.mas_bottom).with.offset(padding.bottom);
}];
```

Comment: Apple's gotten a lot closer to this, too, with [`NSLayoutAnchor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutAnchor_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015406) (iOS 9 only, unfortunately).